# How to count 0's & 1's in a matrix using python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix as shown below ,

```
matrix([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
         1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
         1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
         1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
         0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
         0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
         1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

I want to count the 0's and 1's in that matrix.

The code i tried is ,

```
def countZeroes(mat): 
      
    # start from bottom-left 
    # corner of the matrix 
    N = 10; 
    row = N-1; 
    col = 0; 
  
    # stores number of  
    # zeroes in the matrix 
    count = 0; 
  
    while (col < N): 
          
        # move up until 
        # you find a 0 
        while (mat[row][col]): 
              
            # if zero is not found  
            # in current column, we  
            # are done 
            if (row < 0): 
                return count; 
            row = row - 1; 
  
        # add 0s present in 
        # current column to result 
        count = count + (row + 1); 
  
        # move right to 
        # next column 
        col = col + 1; 
  
    return count;
```

The above code is to count 0's.

Could you help me in solving this problem?

I would request you to provide me an answer using loops.

Thanks!

Comment: The number of 1 is the sum, the number of 0 is (number of total elements - sum). For a known matrix a for loop seems more appropriate. What's wrong with your code though?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach, that it doesn't work for counting `1`s with a trivial change?  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: sum(lambda x:sum(x), matrix) --   num of ones    and  len(matrix[0])*len(matrix) - num of ones -- num of zeros

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we don't care at all about the positions of the various 0s and 1s - so, we're not counting on a per-row or per-column basis, then.

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
         1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
         1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
         1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
         0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
         0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
         1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

The pythonic solution would be to use a comprehension inside a call to the built-in `sum()` to just count the number of 1s, then subtract that from the size of the matrix:

```
matrix_height = len(matrix)
matrix_width = len(matrix[0])
num_ones = sum(cell for row in matrix for cell in row)
num_zeroes = (matrix_height * matrix_width) - num_ones
# num_zeroes = 155
```

However, we can also just use two nested `for` loops to count the number of zeroes that way:

```
num_zeroes = 0
for row in matrix:
    for cell in row:
        if cell == 0:
            num_zeroes += 1
# num_zeroes = 155
```

You can see that the comprehension I demonstrated before is essentially just these two for loops, but in a single line.

Comment: Note how I defined `matrix` - just as two lists, the inner ones nested inside the outer one. Where does your `matrix()` function come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() and map() to obtain the number of ones.  Then subtract that number from the total number of elements to obtain the number of zeroes:

```
ones  = sum(map(sum,matrix))
zeros = sum(map(len,matrix))-ones
```